# Decorator for class with non-virtual members

Tags: c++, decorator

I'm trying to use the decorator pattern for the usual purpose to be able to add functionalities to my class while keeping under control the class hierarchy. My difficulty stems from the fact that my class `A` has a member `basicVar` and a method `basicOp()` which deals with some unspecified basic functionality, which are needed but won't be ever changed in any derived class. For this reason I declare A as:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void func() { /* Some default implementation */}
  void basicOp() { /* some basic operation on basicVar*/}
private:
  int basicVar;
}
```

In this way derived classes don't need to implement `basicOp()` and calls to `basicOp()` don't incur in the overhead of a virtual call. Then I implement the decorator base class as:

```
class ADecorator: public A{
protected:
  std::unique_ptr<A> _a;

public:
  ADecorator(std::unique_ptr<A> a): _a(std::move(a)){}
  void func(){ _a->func(); }
  void basicOp(){ _a->basicOp();}
}
```

Specific decorators inheriting from `ADecorator` will override `func()` to provide additional behavior. Now my problem arises: when using a decorator inheriting from `ADecorator` using the `A` interface like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> dec = std::make_unique<Decorator>(std::make_unique<A>());
dec->basicOp();
```

the called method will be `A::basicOp()` which operates on `dec.basicVar` instead of `ADecorator::basicOp()` which operates on the `dec._a.basicVar` member of the object wrapped by the decorator. This will not happen with `func()` since it's virtual. By declaring also `basicOp()` as virtual the problem is solved, but declaring a method virtual just for making it possible to use decorators sounds like screwing the interface.

I'm quite convinced that this must stem from a design error but I can't exactly figure out which one and how to solve it. Maybe the problem is the presence opf a data member in `A`, or the fact that effectively the decorator pattern is meant to be used only with classes with all the methods declared as virtual?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The overhead is so negligible that there is no point in not using it if it solves another problem.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis thanks for your answer. I agree with you, but in my opinion making it virtual might induce some user to think that it is meant to be overridden in classes derived from `A`, while the only class meant to do that is the decorator. Sounds like a bad design to me.

Comment: Since `basicOp` wouldn't be abstract it could be interpreted that the function could be overridden, but doesn't have to be. Together with good documentation ("This function is not meant to be overridden") you just have to trust the users of `A` to not do anything bad. If they do and complain, then you can just say "Hey I told you it wasn't meant to be overridden, you only have yourself to blame!" :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I agree that this is feasible, and probably the way to go. Still, it doesn't smell 100% OK, so before going on I was asking to understand if I am falling into a known pitfall due to a bad design choice.

Comment: @NicolaMori I don't think you can or should work around this problem. You actually want `basicOp` to have virtual behaviour so just declare it virtual ;)

Comment: If you are using C++11 or above, you can also declare `A::basicOp()` as [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) to force a compiler error if someone misses out all your other hints about the function not being meant for override.

Comment: You have a class (ADecorator) that derives from a base class (A). This class want to override the behavior of a member function from its base class. This is the purpose of virtual function, right? So just add virtual....or use another pattern :)

Comment: @Pesho_T If I correctly understand the usage of `final` then using it as tou propose would make it impossible to override `A::basicOp()` as `ADecorator::basicOp()`, so it seems a no-go.
@Bktero I also came to the conclusion that since `ADecorator` wants to override it then it should be virtual, it just feels wrong that `ADecorator` must be the only one allowed to do so. It does not fit with any design principle I know (admittedly, very few).

Comment: @NicolaMori ah yes this is true - apologies. If you say that you don't want `A::basicOp()` to be overridden, am I correct to assume that you will never want your "decorated" objects to ever do anything extra before or after calling it? If so, do you even need to define `ADecorator::basicOp()`? 

Actually, how does your example even compile? With the code you have provided, you are trying to initialise an instance of A with `std::make_unique<A>()`, but `A` is abstract (it's got a pure virtual member function)

Comment: @Pesho_T The decorator should decorate only the behavior of `func()`. And yes, the example won't compile because `A` is abstract, but it was intended just to illustrate the problem. Anyway I modify the original post to correct this issue, thanks.

Comment: @NicolaMori if you only need to decorate `func()`, what is the reason behind having `ADecorator::basicOp()`? If you omitted it, your example would call `A::basicOp()`, without it being virtual.

Comment: @Pesho_T As I explained in the original post, `A::basicOp()` operates on `dec.basicVar`, while the correct behavior is to call  `ADecorator::basicOp()` which operates on the `dec._a.basicVar` member of the object wrapped by the decorator.

Comment: Why are you both inheriting from `A` (creating a member `ADecorator::basicVar`) *and* containing an `A` via `unique_ptr` (with its own `basicVar`)?

Comment: @DavisHerring Because I need to use `ADecorator` polymorphycally as an `A` (i.e. put in in a `std::vector<A*>`).

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `A` being **stateful** is incompatible with decorator use.  You have a contradiction: you said that `basicOp` would never be changed in a derived class, and yet you have a reasonable derived class `ADecorator` that *does* want to change it (by forwarding it to another object).  If `basicOp` could be implemented without any member variables (*e.g.*, it was just a wrapper for some virtual calls), there would be no problem with the inner or outer object executing the calls to it.

One way to solve this is to **separate** that part of `A` into a `ConcreteA` and provide in `A`

```
virtual ConcreteA& getConcrete()=0;
```

Then store `unique_ptr<ConcreteA>` in the decorator and implement `getConcrete` appropriately; anyone using `ConcreteA` **directly** can make the non-virtual call.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had similar ideas in mind but they were extremely confused due to my limited programming skills. Now I think I understand, I'll try your proposal on my real code and see if it fits with my needs, By the way, it's a pity that such a common rule ("decorators are not suitable to be used with stateful classes") doesn't appear in any decorator tutorial I've read, it would have saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the proposal of Davis Herring I reworked `A` as:

```
class A {
public:
  A(): repr{std::make_shared<Representation>()} {}
  virtual void func() { /* Some default implementation */}
  void basicOp() { /* some basic operation on repr->basicVar*/}
protected:
  struct Representation{
    int basicVar;
  }
  A(const std::shared_ptr<Representation> &extRepr){repr = extRepr;};
  std::shared_ptr<Representation> Repr() {return repr;};
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Representation> repr;
}
```

and `ADecorator` as:

```
class ADecorator: public A{
protected:
  std::unique_ptr<A> _a;

public:
  ADecorator(std::unique_ptr<A> a): A(a->Repr()), _a(std::move(a)){}
  void func(){ _a->func(); }
}
```

In this way both the decorator and the decoorated object share the same representation of `A`, and thus `dec->basicOp()` operates for both the decorator and the decorated object.

This looks quite a hack since it makes the representation of `A` available to derived classes, so `A` cannot have truly private members. A better version could be:

```
class A {
public:
  A(): repr{std::make_shared<Representation>()} {}
  virtual void func() { /* Some default implementation */}
  void basicOp() { /* some basic operation on repr->basicVar*/ }
protected:
  class Representation{
    friend class A;
    int basicVar;
  }
  A(const std::shared_ptr<Representation> &extRepr){repr = extRepr;};
  std::shared_ptr<Representation> Repr() {return repr;};
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Representation> repr;
}
```

I don't know if there is any fundamental problem with this implementation (besides the noticeable complexity) but for now it works for me.